# Database mocking with Flask_SQLAalchemy and MariaDB. Failure to create or drop database with create_all and drop_all methods

Tags: python, mocking, mariadb, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I am trying to implement database mocking with flask and unittest. Examples I have seen use Flask-SQLAlchemy's `db.create_all()` and `db.drop_all()` methods with unittest's `setUp()` and `tearDown()` method's to prepare test fixtures. However, these have exclusively been with SQLite. Looking at the [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.create_all), `db.create_all()` creates only the tables and not the database. Similarly, only the tables are deleted with `db.drop_all()`. I am assuming SQLite behaves differently because it is an embedded, file-based RDBMS.

So to my question, how can I implement database mocking with Flask when the database has not yet been created (In my case a MariaDB database)? I see Flask-SQLAlchemy provides the engine with `db.engine` but when I inspect the engine it is specifying my `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`...which specifies the non-existent database.

```
>>> db.engine
Engine(mysql+pymysql://admin@localhost/test_db?charset=utf8mb4)
```

Here is the example from Miguel Grinberg's book Flask Web Development.

```
import unittest
from flask import current_app
from app import create_app, db


class BasicsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()  # raise pymysql.err.OperationalError "Unknown database 'test_db'"

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()
```

`# raise pymysql.err.OperationalError "Unknown database 'test_db'"`

I do think I need to use the available `db.engine` but I am not sure how to use it to implement mocking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to create the user/database before you run your `setUp`:

Connect to the DB and create the DB and user with the SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test_db;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'secretpassword';
GRANT ALL ON test_db.* to admin@localhost;
```